# How to receive an SMS in python and load in to variable with twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio

I'm new python and am just learning about APIs and how I can use them. I have used the Datamuse API to find words that rhyme and I also have used the Twilio API to send SMS to my Phone. I think it would be fun to be able to combine these by sending a word by SMS to the Twilio number and having the python program take this word and text me back 3 words that rhyme with it. My problem is that I do not know how to receive a text using twilio API, I only know how to send.

I have tried researching this but have only found guides on how to send a the same response message to whatever I type and not be able to actually record and store what SMS I sent in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find how to receive and process incoming SMS using Twilio in the documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python)

Before doing this, you should rent a number from twilio for receiving SMS. It would charge you for both allocating number and receiving SMS. I would suggest you do the same thing using Email as the logic would be same if you find cost an issue. You can send and receive email using `smtplib`.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, here is the authoritative source for responding to an SMS sent to Twilio.

[TwiML™ for Programmable SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml)

When you send an SMS to your Twilio number, it will send a Webhook to your application expecting Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) in return.

When Twilio makes the webhook request to your application it includes all the details about the incoming message as form encoded parameters in the body of the request. The incoming message itself is sent as the `Body` parameter, the number that sent the message is sent as the `From` parameter. You can see all the parameters that will be sent in [the documentation under Request Parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters).

You can then use the `Body` parameter to make the request to the Datamuse API. When you get a response back from the Datamuse API, you can respond back to Twilio with the result using the TwiML [`<Message>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message).

[TwiML™ Message:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message)

[Twilio Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLjSNfoJCYc&list=PLqrz4nXepkz5sdhaee8F5HXoLqp_ZiVn6)